# Radio signal flows through glass

Tags: signal, antenna, radio, physics, microwave

With these antennas; how does the signal flow through the glass?

Is it also possible across other bands; like 2.4GHz Wi-Fi signals?

---

[image: Glass-Mount]
Specifically tuned for the 4G NextG / 3G spectrum for optimum reception performance. 
Operates at 5db gain. Suits: All handsfree car kits / cradles that require external antennas.

GSM 900MHz / 1,800MHz
3G 2,100MHz
NextG 850MHz
FME Connection
Whip 1 Gain 5dB
Cable Length 5m

Comment: The same way the light gets through the window.

Comment: No. It's near field coupling at the base of the antenna pod.

Comment: For lower frequencies, magnetic coupling is probably more efficient than that very small-value capacitor with a wide plate spacing (through the glass).

Answer (score 5):

The glass acts like the dielectric of a capacitor, with the plates being the structures stuck on opposite sides of the glass, I think...

Comment: No doubts.  That is exactly how they work.